# after_create callback not seeming to work correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following code with the log info. The global_id value is set to attr_accessible

This one works

code:

```
Location.update(model[:id],:global_id => gi[:id])
```

log

```
before location save
  Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` WHERE `locations`.`id` = 280 LIMIT 1
 (0.3ms)  UPDATE `locations` SET `global_id` = 11490, `updated_at` = '2012-02-16 04:48:17' WHERE `locations`.`id` = 280
after location save
```

This one doesn't and I'm not sure why. Any ideas:

code:

```
User.update(model[:id],:global_id => gi[:id])
```

log:

```
here is more info
 here i am and I am a user
 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 31 LIMIT 1
  (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'jj@jxx.com' AND `users`.`id` != 31) LIMIT 1
after my user update
```

Any ideas why this second one doesn't work?

thx

edit #1 
Both models have this:

```
after_create SaveGlobalInfo
```

with that class being:

```
class SaveGlobalInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.after_create(model)
    gi=GlobalIdentification.create()
    if (model.class.name=='Location')
      puts "before location save"
      Location.update(model[:id],:global_id => gi[:id])
      puts "after location save"
    elsif (model.class.name=='User')
      puts "here i am and I am a user"
      User.update(model[:id],:global_id => gi[:id])
      puts "after my user update"
    end
```

Comment: added above in edit #1 - that select I'm not sure what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess it's because you're failing some kind of validation. The test being performed with the second SQL call is to ensure uniqueness on your `email` field. What if this is failing and the record can't be saved?

This is especially odd:

```
after_create SaveGlobalInfo
```

You can create helper classes for callbacks, but I've never seen them as actual ActiveRecord models before. Maybe you mean to define a module?

Comment: thx - the ActiveRecord was probably creep from copying. Thx for pointing that out. There was a password validation on the update that was causing it to not update correctly. Rectitfied by using update_attribute on that specific instance of the model which worked. thx